# Pass Session from c# to vb on same project

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, session

Hi i have this c# Webform project and i added this existing webform in vb but i needa session to pass the session from c# to vb 
seems like vb cant get the session even if has the same session name is this even possible to do without the use of database?

C# part:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            personnelData();
            ITSystems();
            QRSystems();
            Session.Add("UserName", "040079");

        }
```

Vb part:

```
<body>
<%
    Set MyConn = server.createobject("ADODB.Connection")
    MyConn.connectionstring = "Provider=MSDAORA.1;User ID=****; Password=****;Data Source=*****"
    MyConn.Open

    Dim strSQL, strSessID, strURL

    strSQL = "DELETE FROM TBLUSERSESSION WHERE EMPID = '" & Session("UserName") & "'"
    MyConn.Execute strSQL

    strSQL = "INSERT INTO TBLUSERSESSION VALUES ('" & Session("UserName") & "', SYS_GUID(), SYSTIMESTAMP)"
    MyConn.Execute strSQL

    Set mySession = MyConn.Execute("SELECT SESSIONID FROM TBLUSERSESSION WHERE EMPID = '" & Session("UserName") & "'")
    If mySession.EOF = False Then
        strSessID = mySession.Fields("SESSIONID")
    End If

    strURL = "http://sample/rewards/rewards/default.aspx?id=" & strSessID
    Response.Write "<script>"
    Response.Write "window.open('" & strURL & "', '_blank');"
    Response.Write "</script>"

    MyConn.Close
    Set MyConn = Nothing
%>
</body>
```

Sorry for my bad english

Comment: If VB and C# runs in the same hosting context (same website, same project in vs...), I don't see any reason why one could not access session of the other (but I don't remember if I already did that). Show us some code.

Comment: okey i edited my question

Comment: Same web app? -- `x = Session("UserName")`. Different app, same server - memory mapped files could help

Comment: its a same application

Comment: To figure what happens, I would suggest you to do a simple example; with just a button and a Response.Write (or Label) to set the Session element on a side, and to display it on the other. We don't care about you're sql code (which has itself a lot of problems)